# U~U(0,1) and Xt = sin(2*pi*u*t), t = 1,2,3,.... Does Xt (t is a suffix of X) is strictly stationary, why or why not?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

The time series X_t = sin (2*pi*U*t), where t=1,2,... and U follows uniform (0,1). 
Does X_t is strictly stationary?